# Putting a whole code inside the ()?

Tags: android-studio

This is basically what is code looks like...

```
musicSwitch.setOnCheckChangeListener();
```

I watched a video tutorial on youtube, and then he did this to the code...

```
musicSwitch.setOnCheckChangeListener
(
         new CompoundButton.OnCheckChangeListener()
         {
              @Override
              public void onCheckChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
              {
                    if(isChecked)
                    {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Music ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    app.setMedia_electronicloop_state(true);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Music OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    app.setMedia_electronicloop_state(false);
                    }
              }

         }
);
```

He added that whole line of code inside the "()" of

```
musicSwitch.setOnCheckChangeListener();\
```

It is really boggling me off, because I don't understand how it should work.
I believe that the code that must be put inside the "()" are variables that the values will inherited from. Please help me understand this

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/24170564/8024897

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setOnCheckedChangeListener arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24170564/setoncheckedchangelistener-arguments)